# How to fix spacing when creating collapsible menus and submenus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using css and javascript to create a collapsible menu that is the width of the webpage and categorizes different types of expenditure. There are submenus that relate to specific types of expenditure. For example inside living costs, there is a submenu of household costs.

The issue I am having is in increasing the height of a dropdown when a submenu is opened inside it. At the moment the when a submenu is opened, the content becomes hidden as the height of the dropdown it is inside does not increase in height.

The javascript function which I am using does not increase the height of the original dropdown which the submenu lies in when the submenu is opened.

So far I have tried using recursion to solve this issue but to no avail.

https://jsfiddle.net/buckler2/vu84wqLa/29/ - running version of code

//css for dropdown

```
<style> 
.collapsible {
 background-color: #777;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
background-color: #555;
}

.content {
height: 800px;
padding:18px;

transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

//Html example

```
<html>
 <button class="collapsible">Expenditure</button>
  <div class="content">
  <button class="collapsible">Living Expenses</button>
        <div class="content">
           <button class="collapsible">Household expenses</button>
             <div class = "content">
                  //some list of household expenses
             </div>
            //some list of other living expenses
         </div>

       //some list of other types of expenditure
  </div>
</html>
```

//Javascript for dropdown

```
<script> 
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling; 
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: you have to remove the `height:800px` property and let height expand as needed in order to show all content. This might mean that you need to modify your original design of menus to account fot this fact

Comment: Hi @NikosM., thanks for the help and quick response! That still hasn't help resolve my issue however. The dropdown menus still aren't increasing in size as submenus are opened. You can run the code here https://jsfiddle.net/buckler2/vu84wqLa/29/ to give a better idea of my issue. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue was that content.scrollHeight value can't be read at the time of the function. You can see it happening when you try opening the menu a second time - it will show the full content (at least on the JSFiddle).

Changing the maxHeight value to a fixed number solves the issue:

```
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = "1000px";
    }
  });
}
```